# ggplot tooltip on Rmarkdown html document

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

I am having problems including a tooltip for ggplot in the Rmarkdown html output. Please don't get me wrong I read the shiny interactive plots guide but I am just confuse as the R markdown does not have the UI and Server components in the same structure a shiny apps does. So my questions is how to include a ggplot tooltip on an Rmarkdown html output.

Below the example

````
---
title: "testing"
date: "30 October 2015"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library (ggplot2)
library (shiny)
library (shinyapps)
```
## R Markdown
```{r cars}
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))+
geom_point()
renderText({
paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
})
```
````

Comment: Maybe you this link can help http://al2na.github.io/Rmarkdown_JSviz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `Shiny` app and then embedding the app into my `Rmarkdown` document.

To embed the app I used the instructions provided on the `Rmarkdown` homepage for inline applications

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html

For the tooltips the instructions are provided from shiny app here

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample

```
library(googleVis)
Scatter1 <- gvisScatterChart(cars)
plot(Scatter1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that mate. I looks pretty good I just want to stay on the Hadley Wickham’s universe for this one.